# android SurfaceView add callback Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, surfaceview, surfaceholder

i try to play video from url.i wrote some code witch can play video.now i want to use `Asynctask` class to load video from URl.when i used Asynctask i have RuntimeException
the eclipse error is : `Cannot create handler inside thread that has no called Looper.prepare()`
this is a my source

```
  public class Layout1 extends Fragment  {
public static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
SurfaceHolder holder;

MediaController mcontroller;
Handler handler;
String videoUrl;
SurfaceHolder.Callback callback;

private ConnectionDetector cd;

ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    callback = new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            // the holder reference is already passed as arg0 here
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            try {
                // progressDialog.dismiss();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mcontroller.setEnabled(true);

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {

        }
    };

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout1, null);
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.screen_tutorial_video_surface);


    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please Wait... ", "Loading... ");
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.show();
    mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(callback);

    Log.e("MainActivity result is .......", MainActivity.intent_result);
    handler = new Handler();


        playVideo();


    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            if(dialog!=null)
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private void playVideo() {
    mcontroller = new MediaController(getActivity());

    mcontroller.setEnabled(true);
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),
            Uri.parse(Global.yutubeDownloadUrl));

    mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);


    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


}
```

if i call `playVideo()` function Instead of Asynctask Class then everythink is ok,but i want to use Asynctask
 now i have errror in this line

```
mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(callback);
```

how i can solve my problem? video witch i  must play from url is so large and i want to use Asynctask Class

Comment: Play video without `AsyncTask`. `MediaPlayer` is designed to stream from web and also from local. If you don't want streaming then you can download the stream and store it in SD card and play later.

Comment: hmm.but i want show loader  before video started.this is a my problem and thet's why i use asynctask

Comment: Show `ProgressDialog` inside `onCreateView` method before starting the  video. Use interfaces with `MediaPlayer` for the video playback events.

Comment: i know how i can show  ProgressDialog  but when i dismis this ProgressDialog ???

Comment: `MediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener()` dismiss it inside that

Comment: thank you. i updated my code and please see it.but i have  another problem.i replaced this fragment another activity and  before replaced i have black windows

Comment: do you see black window before the video starts playing?

Comment: yes sir @intrepidkarthi

Comment: Try giving background color for your `VideoView`. And also once your fragment is called, you should be seeing the `ProgressDialog` right?

Comment: meybe you are not right. i use SurfaceView  and my surfaceview background is #00000000.but this is  not problem.before video start program freez

Comment: if you are just playing a video, you can just do it with a videoview.